# How can I insert an image into a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a div from my html file that has styling from my css file as well. When I try to append a .jpg picture from my .js file to the div, it doesn't utilize the already defined styling. Am I appending the picture incorrectly? I don't quite understand why it's not using the defined styling.

```js
var img = new Image();

img[0] = new Image();
img[0].src = '1.jpg';
img[1] = new Image();
img[1].src = '2.jpg';

document.getElementById('picture').append(img[0]);
```

```css
#picture {
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture">

</div>
```

Comment: Why the `[0]`?.. why `var img = new Image();` and that acting as if it's an Array

Comment: I just edited the code but my goal is to have an array of images that I can add an event listener that cycles through the images.

Comment: And where is your CSS for the `img` tag?

Comment: Consider using semantic html and not just a div

Answer (score 1):

First, a quickfix: Use an array `[]`

```js
var img = [];

img[0] = new Image();
img[0].src = 'https://placehold.it/60x60/0bf';
img[1] = new Image();
img[1].src = 'https://placehold.it/60x60/fob';

document.getElementById('picture').append(img[0], img[1]);
```

```css
#picture {
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture">

</div>
```

Secondly: use an array of paths and use it to create your images without repeating much code:

```js
const images = [
  'https://placehold.it/60x60/0bf',
  'https://placehold.it/60x60/fob',
];

const DF_images = images.reduce((DF, src) => {
  const Img = new Image();
  Img.src = src;
  DF.append(Img);
  return DF;
}, new DocumentFragment());

document.getElementById('picture').append(DF_images);
```

```css
#picture {
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture">

</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and the actual image when appending is inheriting any of the css styling I have defined. It adds the picture on top of the actual picture div I have.

Comment: @Terry but you did not defined any styling for your `img` tag in CSS. only for the parent `#picture` DIV Element. Also, notice (if that's the issue) that ID **must be unique** per-page.

Comment: My goal is to ultimately create a slideshow. I was first trying to correctly make sure the image got appended before adding more features/functionality.

Answer (score 0):

append - Maybe you using jquery ?

Default , you try "appendChild"

```
<div id="picture"></div>
<input type='button' onclick="foo" value='Add New Image'>
<script>
function foo()
{
  var img=new Array(2);
  img[0]=new Image();
  img[0].src="1.jpg";
  document.getElementById('picture').appendChild(img[0]);
}
</script>
```

If use Jquery

```
<script>
funcntion foo()
{
  $("#picture").append("<img src='1.jpg'>");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you add "width:10px" thats why image not set on box.
See this maybe your problem is solve.

```js
var img = [];

img[0] = new Image();
img[0].src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495465798138-718f86d1a4bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80';
img[1] = new Image();
img[1].src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495465798138-718f86d1a4bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80';

document.getElementById('picture').append(img[0], img[1]);
```

```css
#picture {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture">

</div>
```